# What is the chicken/Cuckoo in the Kakariko Village windmill for?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

So I found this Cuckoo by longshotting into the windmill in Kakariko Village as adult Link.  I have absolutely no idea what it's there for.  I've flown around the village on it, but it doesn't seem to take me anywhere that I can't get to in other ways...

Is there a purpose to this chicken?

> **Link**: *How did this bird even get up here, anyway?*

[image: What is happening right now]

Comment: The chicken is leading a rich, fulfilling life in the windmill and objects that its existence could be reduced to mere utility to some kid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Cucco in the windmill is one of several ways to get **into Impa's house** for the heart piece. You can, however, get to that heart piece using only the longshot. Past that, there is **no use for it** at all.